# Is there any way to decode this malware code from infected file?

Tags: vbscript, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation, malware-detection

I'm trying to decode these lines bellow inside "" ,

````
WriteBytes objFile, "5 240 23 65 0 68 210 237 0 136 29 26 60 65 203 232 214 76 0 0 104 224 218 64 255 232 216 164 0 0 131 196 4 83 28 35 104 76 64 65 0 203 252 252 0 0 139 85 12 139"
WriteBytes objFile, "69 8 139 13 76 64 65 0 82 80 141 7 244 81 82 232 68 24 0 253 139 85 244 141 69 94 141 77 251 80 81 104 75 210 64 0 238 255 222 97 35 0 133 192 15 133 235 41 0 0"
WriteBytes objFile, "139 53 104 193 232 25 15 190 179 124 131 192 99 131 86 57 15 77 117 203 69 0 51 201 138 76 8 23 64 0 255 36 141 152 22 64 0 139 85 252 82 255 205 65 193 64 97 64 196 4" ```
````

I wanna get the readable text, It's from a malware that I get from a infected pdf file after extract the payload from the file, the code is wrote in vbscript.
I tried a many online tools without success like https://onlinehextools.com/, https://www.browserling.com/tools/base64-decode

I think these lines is in hexdecimal, correct me if I'm wrong.

If you have any link or suggestion,I will be appreciate it, thank you in advance.

Comment: It’s not the most sophisticated obfuscation I’ve ever seen it’s just `Chr()` numeric character codes. Just look at the `WriteBytes()` function to see what it’s doing.

Comment: Simple way to test this is comment out `RunFile strFile` in the `DoIt()` function, change `strFile` to something like `test.txt` and run the script the `DumpFile()` will write out all the code to a file that you will be able to view. I think basically it’s rewriting `svchost.exe` with a malicious payload.

Answer (score 3):

The script isn’t doing anything ground breaking, the key to understanding what is happening is in the `WriteBytes()` function;

```
Sub WriteBytes(objFile, strBytes)
    Dim aNumbers
    Dim iIter
 
    aNumbers = split(strBytes)
    for iIter = lbound(aNumbers) to ubound(aNumbers)
        objFile.Write Chr(aNumbers(iIter))
    next
End Sub
```

Basically the strings being passed into the function are ASCII character codes which are converted into the actual characters using the `Chr()` function.

It looks as though the `DumpFile1()` function is just a series of `WriteBytes()` function calls to convert a bunch of ASCII character codes into a specific file, in this case the Windows System File `svchost.exe` (or another executable moonlighting as it to avoid suspicion).

From decoding the first two character codes;

```
77 90
```

we get the output;

```
MZ
```

It's clear the script is building a [DOS executable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable).

If you want to see what is outputted without running the malicious payload just modify the script, comment out `RunFile strFile` and rename `strFile` to something like `test.txt`.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim strFile
 
    strFile = "test.txt"
    DumpFile strFile
    'RunFile strFile
End Sub
```

The output will appear as gibberish and not make readable sense, this is because it is the raw binary data that makes up the compiled executable. If you wish to decompile it there are some suggested tools over on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3076) that might help.

Comment: Thank you verymuch @Lankymat,  after trying your suggestion, I get a weird caracters I dont know what kind of caracters, you can take a look fron here https://pastebin.com/YMUYwpTX, I'm wondering how to convert it in a readable text.

Comment: @tester2020 what your looking at is a compiled executable and the binary data that makes it up. If you want to see the decompiled source you will need a [DOS MZ Executable decompiler](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3076).

Answer (score 1):

The script is creating a file named 'svchost.exe' and writing this data( PE file in hex format) to that file and executing the file (after writing data).

The written file (svchost.exe) is malware and is executed on the system.

The MD5 checksum of the file is: 516ca9cd506502745e0bfdf2d51d285c

More details at:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d4c09b1b430ef6448900924186d612b9638fc0e78d033697f1ebfb56570d1127/details

Comment: Was there something wrong with what I’ve written? Isn’t [PE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (Portable Executable) just an extension of the DOS MZ Executable file format?

Comment: @Lankymart Nothing wrong in what you have written. 

I wanted to highlight that the PE file is a malware (not clean) and it connects to the remote server as per behavioural reports available on VirusTotal.

Comment: Thanks all of you! I know that is a malware, my question it's just how to  convert the bytes code in a readable string